# When is an oscillating integral small?

Tags: integration, analysis, fourier-analysis

I hope, the title is not too confusing. My question is the following:
We all know the Riemann-Lebesgue-Lemma stating that for $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, one has
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty} \int f(x)\,e^{ikx}\,dx=0. $$
Intuitively this means that the fast oscillation of $e^{ikx}$ makes the integral small.

Question: Can one show something like
$$\int f(x)\,e^{i\phi(x)}\,dx \leq \int f(x)\,e^{i\psi(x)}\,dx, $$
if $\phi>\psi$?

(or maybe, if $\phi-\psi\geq\text{(some constant)}$, or so)

Thanks,

Frank

Answer (score 2):

If it was true, the Fourier transform of an even $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ function would be always increasing on $\mathbb{N}$. This is clearly false, just by considering $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$. Notice that neither the opposite inequality holds, since nothing forces the Fourier transform to be monotonic someway.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry! The < should have been a >, of course!
I corrected it above.